# Asynchronous feedparser requests

Tags: python, asynchronous, rss, feedparser

I'm using feedparser (Python) to get some RSS entries from several websites.

How can I do asynchronous requests using feedparser? I mean, I want to get some RSS entries but I don't want to wait for the response. A callback function should be called when I get the response from the feedparser request. After the request (and probably before the reply) I want to do some computation.

Thank you all,
Hugo

Answer (score 5):

You're probably better off to **decouple** the *fetching* from the *parsing*. Feedparser is an amazing parsing library, but probably *not the best HTTP client libary*. Luckily that's fairly easy to do as Feedparser can also [parse a blob of text](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/introduction.html#parsing-a-feed-from-a-string).

Then, this means you can **pick any HTTP library** to actually do the polling, as long as it supports your asyncrhonous requirement. You'll probably end up using something like Twisted and its [WebClient](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/web/howto/client.html).

Another solution is to of course avoid doing all that expensive polling yourself and rely on a solution like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com/) which will use webhooks to send you only what's new in a given feed.

Answer (score 2):

**2019 update**

**Use asyncio**

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import async_timeout
import feedparser

import pprint

INTERVAL = 60

async def fetch(session, url):
    with async_timeout.timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def fetchfeeds(loop, feedurls, ircsock):
    last_entry = None

    feeds = []

    for url in feedurls:
        feeds.append({'url':url, 'last':""})

    while True:
        for feed in feeds:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
                html = await fetch(session, feed['url'])
                rss = feedparser.parse(html)
                if feed['last']:
                    if feed['last']['title'] != rss['entries'][0]['title'] and feed['last']['link'] != rss['entries'][0]['link']:
                        print("new entry")
                        feed['last'] = rss['entries'][0]

                        print("MSG {}".format(feed['last']['title']))
                        print("MSG {}".format(feed['last']['link']))
                else:
                    feed['last'] = rss['entries'][0]

        await asyncio.sleep(INTERVAL)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(fetchfeeds(loop, ['https://n-o-d-e.net/rss/rss.xml',
    "http://localhost:8000/rss.xml"], None))
```

Comment: nice answer, *but* you aren't processing the header from the REST request, which means you are *losing* both the e-tag and last-modified fields!

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question, why exactly do we need etag header and what will you do with last modified

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, i ll test this first on my code and update the one here if it works :)

Comment: @vgoklani etag and modified are available directly only if you use feedparser module to fetch the urls, i am using the AIOhttp library, returns None for both of them, my guess is that i ll have to extract it from aiohttp response headers

Comment: YES - you need to manually extract them from the headers. Note - they aren't always there, depends on the source.... I also use aiohttp with uvloop, that's the best way to go :)